# Replacing node path based on a given path and appending the rest of the path in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help in figuring out how to best do this in python 3.x :

(Note: this is not a OS path structure. It is path/node structure for zookeeper)

```
def join_paths(base_path, *relative_paths):
    rel_paths = [ x.strip('/') for x in relative_paths]
    result_path = base_path.rstrip('/')
    for rel_path in rel_paths:
        result_path = result_path + '/' + rel_path #possibly here some replace can be done ??
    print (result_path)

join_paths("/Windows/kin_test","/Windows/kin_dev/path1/path2")
```

The output is

> /Windows/kin_test/Windows/kin_dev/path1/path2

What I want the output to be is (replacing the first 2 folder with the base path since it is 2 folder deep).

> /Windows/kin_test/path1/path2

Whatever the path is in the 1st (base path) that should be appended by the relative path with replacing relative path length as per the base path.

Another example

if my base path is `/Windows/kin_test/base_01` and relative path is `/Windows/kin_dev/path1/path2` then the final path should be  `/Windows/kin_test/base_01/path2`

if base is just `/` then final path should be should be `/Windows/kin_dev/path1/path2`

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Thanks @wwii. I will update my question that this is not a OS folder. This is zookeeper node path. If you can give some example on how to accomplish what I am trying to do, I will appreciate. I did look at the os package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a colleague's help - able to answer my own question. Hope this helps future visitors :

```
def join_paths(base_path, relative_paths):

    # Taking care of first case where base_path is "/" root
    if base_path ==  "/":
        return relative_paths
    # Convert the base_path to a list by splitting at "/" ["", "folder1", "folder2"]
    base_path_list = base_path.split("/")
    # Convert the relative_paths to a list by splitting at "/" ["", "folder1", "folder2"]
    relative_paths_list = relative_paths.split("/")
    # Take difference between length of base_path_list and length of relative_paths_list
    len_diff = len(relative_paths_list) - len(base_path_list)
    # Validate if difference in length is greater than 0 else it wont find 
    # the sub list it needs to append
    if len_diff > 0:
        # Get last 'n' elements from relative_paths_list where n is len_diff
        list_to_append = relative_paths_list[-len_diff:]
        # Join the base path list with sub-list we just created above
        final_list = base_path_list + list_to_append
        # Join the elements in list with "/"
        return "/".join(final_list)
     elif len_diff == 0:
        final_list = base_path_list
        return "/".join(final_list)
     else:
        print("SOmething is really wrong")

# run the code 
print(join_paths("/Windows/kin_test/path2", "/Windows/kin_dev/path2/path3"))
```

Link : https://www.onlinegdb.com/SJFE_IpSL